# new Fragment is not opening when recyclerView item is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment, onclicklistener

i've been trying to launch a new fragment on click, i found on the internet this is way, when clicking the methode gets provoked but nothing happens

```
public class PlacesRecyclerAdapter extends  
RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener{
//some code

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)  context;
TextView t = v.findViewById(R.id.placeName);
fragment = new DetailFragment(getCurrentPlace((String) t.getText()));
FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.tabItem, fragment);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();

}

//some code
 }
```

for the getCurrentPLace() it's a method that return a Place Object, i've checked it with the debbuger, and it works as expected

here is the DetailFragment.class code

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

private MainActivity.Place place;
TextView name;

public DetailFragment(MainActivity.Place place) {
this.place = place;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
                      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_place_fragment, container, false);

name.setText(place.getTitle());

return view;
}
}
```

here is the XML with the id R.id.tabItem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/tabItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/placesRecycleView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

PS: i tried the solutions on the similair questions, but nothing worked.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use the Navigation Component, then you'll have to navigate easily with just one line command.

Comment: Did you set `setOnClickListener(this)` to the recycler view item?

Comment: @grabarz121 where exactly i should put that.

Comment: @NasreddineBouchemel Inside `onBindViewHolder()` method, it should be `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(this)`

Comment: @grabarz121 i did it, the onClick method gets provoked but nothing happens :/

Comment: do you want to show the fragment in the recyclerview item? or you want to show it separately in the activity?

Comment: @rahat i want to open it seperatly when clicking on the recyclerView item

Comment: R.id.tabItem, seems like the view is a tab Item, is it?. can you share your layout file xml code. the fragment should be replaced upon a container view like FrameLayout

Comment: @rahat yes it is a tab item, i added the xml

Comment: The answer below didn't work?

Comment: @rahat it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way at first is to use Interface.

```
Interface onClick{
    void click();
}
```

and implement it in the constructor of the class :

```
class PlacesRecyclerAdapter(onClick click)...
```

and use it like

```
t.setOnClickListener{
  click.click();
}
```

and when you define the adapter in your activity, this method (click) implement and you can define this in the activity instead of the adapter

```
fragment = new DetailFragment(getCurrentPlace((String) t.getText()));
FragmentTransaction transaction =    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.tabItem, fragment);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

but the best way to avoid these problems is to use the navigation component.

Comment: where exactly i sould put `t.setOnClickListener`

Comment: [RecyclerView with ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#implement-adapter) follow this link you have to declare a method in viewHolder class and put that code there and call it in onBindViewHolder if you want to  pass data to your fragment the method of the interface must have input like this -> void click(String name);